# How to store the URLs crawled with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a web crawler that crawls for news stories on a web page.

I know how to use the XpathSelector to scrape certain information from the elements in the page.

However I cannot seem to figure out how to store the URL of the page that was just crawled.

```
class spidey(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidey'
    start_urls = ['http://nytimes.com'] # urls from which the spider will start crawling
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'page/\d+']), follow=True), 
        # r'page/\d+' : regular expression for http://nytimes.com/page/X URLs
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+']), callback='parse_articles')]
        # r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+' : regular expression for http://nytimes.com/YYYY/MM/title URLs
```

I want to store every link that passes those rule.

What would I need to add to parse_articles to store the link in my item?

```
def parse_articles(self, response):
    item = SpideyItem()
    item['link'] = ???
    return item
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

response.url is what you are looking for.

See [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects) on response object and check [this](https://github.com/alecxe/broken-links-checker/blob/master/broken_links_spider.py) simple example.